# having count don´t work

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I need to list the description of locality and the number of claims of each, just in casso claims where the amount exceeds 10

I tried with

```
select l.descripcion, count(r.cod_cliente) from reclamo r
        join cliente c on r.cod_cliente = c.cod_cliente 
        join localidad l on c.cod_localidad = l.cod_localidad
        group by r.nro_reclamo
        having count(*)>10;
```

but it does not work, as I solve?

sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2771/7

Comment: group by column and select column are different.. plz confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select l.descripcion, count(r.cod_cliente) from reclamo r
        join cliente c on r.cod_cliente = c.cod_cliente 
        join localidad l on c.cod_localidad = l.cod_localidad
        group by l.descripcion
        having count(r.cod_cliente) >10;
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2771/10/0)